# MVC5 Identity Roles Role Name Intellisense

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-mvc-5, intellisense, asp.net-identity

No code as I have no idea if this is even possible.

Is it possible to get the Roles available in the Db (Created in `Seed()` at the moment) to work as an Enum or something similar so that instead of remembering all the roles etc it is possible to use intellisense?

If it is possible could you show me how please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a class with constant fields and use that in the app, also when seeding the database. A downside is that the roles are defined in both the application and the database.

```
public static class RoleNames
{
   public const string Administrator = "ADMIN";

   public const string Customer = "CUSTOMER";
}
```

This avoids magic strings in your code and allows easier refactoring.

Comment: Yeah I think this is probably the better way to go.

Comment: Just a comment to mention that you want to make sure when you initialize your user that you also do the conversion from the database to the RoleNames.whatever, then add them into the users roles. Maybe obvious to some people but yea.